# Django - Are there security risks with not implementing is_valid and cleaned_data for forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I'd prefer to implement A and C instead of B and D, because I'd like to implement my custom css for the form in the html css files without having to deal with forms.py or formatting the css in python. **Do A and C present any security risks versus B and D? Are there any other downsides of using A and C?**

```
#A
if request.method == "POST":
    user = authenticate(email=request.POST["email"], password=request.POST["password"])

#B
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

#C
if request.method == "POST":
    contact_name = request.POST["contact"]

#D
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact']
```

Comment: Unvalidated unsanitized user inputs are _always_ a security issue, and specially on the net. And you don't have to bypass form validation to "implement your custom css" - there's no shortage of resources on the topic.

Comment: Can I implement the is_valid function for A and C, without a forms.py? I inputed my form directly into the html template without a forms.py in A and C.

Comment: Then redo your templates. Form validation is not trivial, Django forms DO work, so stop trying to reinvent the proverbial squared wheel.

Comment: ok I'll do that. Can you confirm I should always have a forms.py to implement forms correctly in Django?

Comment: Where you put your forms doesn't really matter (even if the convention is to have them in a forms.py module), the important point is to  (correctly) use forms for user inputs. If you care about security and maintainability that is...

Answer (score 1):

There is no security risk on **A** and **C**.  is_valid() method to run validation and return a boolean designating whether the data was valid. 
More you can refer to :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean